# assert() in CUDA 5.5

Tags: cuda

I've just upgraded from CUDA 5.0 to 5.5 and all my VS2012 CUDA projects have stopped compiling due to a problem with assert(). To repro the problem, I created a new CUDA 5.5 project in VS 2012 and added the code straight from Programming Guide and got the same error.

```
__global__ void testAssert(void)
{
    int is_one = 1;
    int should_be_one = 0;
    // This will have no effect
    assert(is_one);
    // This will halt kernel execution 
    assert(should_be_one);
}
```

This produces the following compiler error:

```
kernel.cu(22): error : calling a __host__ function("_wassert") from a __global__ function("testAssert") is not allowed
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: `assert` is a macro which is translates to `_wassert()`. I'm surprised that it actually worked in CUDA 5.

Comment: Are you including `assert.h` ?  For compile problems, it's really more convenient if you post a complete reproducer, rather than just a code fragment.  i.e. an entire program that I can copy, paste, and compile, without adding anything or editing anything.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: assert works fine in CUDA, see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#assertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are including `assert.h`, and make sure you are targeting sm_20 or later. Also check you're *not* including Windows headers, and if you are then try without.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in code generation setting. I had the following in my .vcxproj file: compute_20,sm_20;compute_30,sm_35 but for some reason it was ignored after the upgrade. Resetting it back to the same value helped to solve the problem.